# Is there a better way to write Interfaces?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to provide an array with an interface. At the same time, however, I would like to set an empty array as standard. Now VS-Code shows me at this point always an error. I know these interfaces have no effect on the code. Can I handle this somehow?

this works, but makes the interface redundant

```js
private steamArray : {[index: string] : net.Socket} | Array<undefined> = [];
```

this code always shows me an error when initializing

```js
private steamArray : {[index: string] : net.Socket} = [];
```

Its only a visual error, that makes it hard to find existing code errors 
[image: Visual error]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide what error? I assume smth wrong is with net.Socket, is it a type? Please provide the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your `steamArray` is an array of your custom interface. Then you are missing a bracket `[]`:

```
private steamArray : {[index: string] : net.Socket}[] = [];
```

You can set the interface explicitly for better readability:

```
type MyInterface = {[index: string] : net.Socket}
private steamArray : MyInterface[] = [];
```

Comment: thanks, there was actually my mistake :)